# Sliding window method over a large range using numpy vectorization

Tags: pandas, numpy, sliding-window

I'm trying to implement a sliding window method for a genomics dataset that I have, over a fairly long range (upwards of 50k nucleotide's). My approach so far works fine, however is fairly slow (taking several seconds per range, and several minutes per range at intervals >150k bp). Here is my code so far:

```
import numpy as np


VectorizedRange = np.arange(Start, End)#Start, End genomic flags on the reference genome
SlidingWindow = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(VectorizedRange, 100)#100 = the window size

GroupedDictFrame = pd.DataFrame({"Bins":GenomeRange})
GroupedDictFrame["ReadCov"] = 0
GroupedDictFrame["ReadSeq"] = [list() for _ in range(len(GroupedDictFrame.index.values))]
GroupedDictFrame.set_index(keys=["Bins"], inplace=True, drop=True)

def Appender(Start, End, Width, Seq):
     AvgCov = 0
     SeqList = []
     if End <= Window[-1]:
        AvgCov += 1
        SeqList.append(Seq)
     elif End > Window[-1]:
        AvgCov += (Window[-1] - Start)/Width
        SeqList.append(Seq[0:(Window[-1] - Start)])
            
     GroupedDictFrame.loc[Window[0], "ReadCov"] += AvgCov 
     GroupedDictFrame.loc[Window[0], "ReadSeq"] = SeqList

for Window in SlidingWindow:
        
    SubsetBAM = BAMFrame[(
        (BAMFrame["start_coord"]>=Window[0])&
        (BAMFrame["start_coord"]<=Window[-1])
        )].reset_index(drop=True)
    
    SubsetBAM.apply(
        lambda x: Appender(x.start_coord, 
                           x.end_coord,
                           x.width_lis,
                           x.seq_lis), axis=1
        )
```

I think my vectorization isn't the best, any suggestions for speeding this up?

Comment: Looks like you're defining the Appender again in the for loop. Put it before the for loop and see if it improves your speed

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew Wow that was dumb of me, yeah it improved the speed a bit, but it's still pretty slow all things considered. I think this has to do with the for loop itself, I'm wondering if there's a way to use numpy instead

Comment: Try to do line profiling to see the bottleneck. I think what makes your code slow is due to the `Appender` Anyway, you can try to post this in `Code Review` SE to get better suggestion :D

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew I think I figured it out, thanks for your help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So I think I figured it out on my own, I'll add my solution in case anyone else faces a similar problem.

Essentially, I stopped subsetting my dataframe containing the small DNA read fragments in the for loop, and did one subset before the loop and converted it to a numpy array.

I removed my function and used numpy.where to do all my logic.

```
import numpy as np


VectorizedRange = np.arange(Start, End)
SlidingWindow = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(VectorizedRange, 100)

GroupedDictFrame = pd.DataFrame({"Bins":GenomeRange})
GroupedDictFrame["ReadCov"] = 0
GroupedDictFrame["ReadSeq"] = [list() for _ in range(len(GroupedDictFrame.index.values))]
GroupedDictFrame.set_index(keys=["Bins"], inplace=True, drop=True)

CoordArray = BAMFrame.loc[:, "start_coord":"end_coord"].to_numpy()

for Window in SlidingWindow:
    ReadCovIn = np.where(((CoordArray[:,1] <= Window[-1]) & (CoordArray[:,0] >= Window[0])), 1, 0)
    ReadCovOut = np.where(((CoordArray[:,1] > Window[-1]) & ((CoordArray[:,0] >= Window[0]) & (CoordArray[:,0] < Window[-1]))),
                          (Window[-1] - CoordArray[:,0])/(CoordArray[:,1] - CoordArray[:,0]), 0)
    
    GroupedDictFrame.loc[Window[0], "ReadCov"] += np.sum((np.sum(ReadCovIn), np.sum(ReadCovOut)))
```

I've gotten it down to ~1 second per gene region which is typically about 50kb (so that would mean the SlidingWindow has a shape of (49900,100)), which is pretty good I think!